# Create variable padding around 1d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
arr= [1,2,3,4]
k = 4 (can be different)
```

so result will be 2 d array. How to do this without using any loop? and can't hard code k.
k and arr can vary as per input.
Must use numpy.pad

```
[[1,2,3,4,0,0,0], #k-1 zeros
 [0,1,2,3,4,0,0],
 [0,0,1,2,3,4,0],
 [0,0,0,1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to do it without a loop (for educational purposes)

```
np.pad(np.tile(arr,[k,1]), [(0,0),(0,k)]).reshape(-1)[:-k].reshape(k,-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension as a one liner :

```
import numpy as np

arr= np.array([1,2,3,4])
k = 4

print( np.array( [ np.pad(arr, (0+i , k-1-i ) ) for i in range(0,k)] ) )
```

Out :

```
[[1 2 3 4 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 3 4 0 0]
 [0 0 1 2 3 4 0]
 [0 0 0 1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: In real world your answer would have been perfect. But the question is no for or while loops or even list comprehension. Hidden loops are ok . @Osamoele

Comment: @Grafins Is there a reason you would refuse to work with any loop ? If it is for speed, you should consider making a dedicated function in cython, using foor loop as you wish there, and it will be faster than in python. At least not slower than the numpy C-implemented functions, that use SIMD and loops internally. Else, i see no real valid reason except for entertainment purposes but should be your challenge in that case ;)

Comment: its part of my programming assignment. So no loops. please understand